# How to convert _id field of all existing documents from type String to Number

Tags: mongodb, datatypes, type-conversion

At one of my collections I have an `_id` field that stores numbers. The field was defined originally in the Mongoose model as `String`. However, all the data concerning this field in the collection contains pure integers stored as strings. I want to preserve all the data in my collection while converting the type of this field (and all associated `_id`'s) from type `String` to type `Number`. Any suggestions as how to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
db.getCollection('test').find().forEach(function (doc) {
    db.getCollection('test').remove({ _id : doc._id});
    tempId = new NumberLong(doc._id);
    doc._id = tempId;
    db.getCollection('test').save(doc);
    } 
);
```

This will do. You may want to add error handling as per your use case. Also make sure you have backup before migrating.

Comment: Thanks. I would also suggest to postpone actual deletion of existing documents until duplication of data completes (i.e. after creating new documents with new _id type), and only then to delete all old documents by:

`.remove({ $type :  x })`

More on MongoDB types can be found here:
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/